# Git won't add modified file

Tags: git, git-add

No idea why this is happening:

```
git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   file (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
starkers@ubuntu:~/Documents/currentWork/protection_demo$ git add --all
starkers@ubuntu:~/Documents/currentWork/protection_demo$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   file (modified content)
```

No matter what I do, `git commit -am`, `git commit -a` the file will not be added to the commit. Any help?

Comment: What about `git add <file>` ?

Comment: Instead of "file", you should post the whole path of the file in question. Also, are you using submodules?

Comment: Is the file in your .gitignore file?

Comment: @chooban Whether or not a tracked file is listed in `.gitignore` doesn't the ability to stage changes in that file, though.

Comment: But do you not need to use the --force option?

Comment: @chooban No; no need if the files in question are *already* being tracked.  The file in question here is listed as "modified", which indicates it's a tracked file.

Comment: Of course! That'll teach me to try answering something after midnight.

Comment: same issue here.  Files are not ignored, I am in correct directory, correct branch but git add . will not stage them.  I use git add . all the time for years and never had this issue

Comment: I have a similar but upside-down problem: I have a "modified" file that doesn't exist, cannot be staged and doesn't go away with `git checkout -- .`  ...  in my case it's a clone from overleaf, I wonder if their git implementation is still a bit buggy?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think maybe Jubobs' comment is correct. Is your "file" a submodule?

This line *(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)* should not appear for normal files.

Here is what I get from git status:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   README.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

You will not see **(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)** and **(modified content)** after my README.txt

So you may need to do what git recommended, work on the content in submodules.

Edit: Previously I thought the "git add ." could solve the issue but now I think it could not.

Comment: `--all` is a valid option of `git-add`. From the `git-add` man page: *`--all` Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching `<pathspec>` but also where the index already has an entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree.*

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! I always use "git add ." . I think now I have to use this option instead

Comment: in my case there was a hidden .git folder in my sub-folder. so i deleted it and the problem was solved

Answer (score 16):

I had this same problem. My personal "aha" was that I had previously added a tracking .git repository file to a subfolder and thus it was seen as a submodule. After removing the .git in the subfolder, it happily joined the rest of my folders as part of just one .git file in the root folder. I didn't even know about submodules so maybe this will help someone as well.

Comment: i removed the .git folder which was accidentally created, the status got fixed. in my case i had to rename the folder/file and then push to the remote. like a work around.

Comment: Same here. For some reason, after I deleted `.git` from the subfolder it stopped tracking it completely, like it didn't exist. So I removed the parent's `.git` as well and redid the initial commit, since that's all the history it had.

Answer (score 8):

had the same problem, no idea why but a .h file would not commit.

So, I renamed it, this deleted original and created new as far a git was concerned. Then I committed these changes. Git was happy.

Then I just renamed it back. Again git was happy to commit.

Cannot explain why this happened, but at least it was fixed.

Comment: For me there was something wrong with the path. I had two different paths to the same file MyDomain.Service/Folder/Folder/MyFile.cs and mydomain.service/Folder/Folder/MyFile.cs (notice the difference in cases). When I remove the file from File Explorer and added a new one with the same code it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this happened to me as well. I had this issue on windows. None of the existing solutions pointed to something wrong on my side at all. I renamed the files, staged, then renamed back to their previous file name, then staged, and all was good.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is relevant or not, but I had the same issue when switching between Linux and Windows. I had 2 files one WEB.config and another web.config since Windows is not case sensitive it seems to have gotten confused. I renamed the file commited renamed back and commited again seems to have works.

Comment: same for Mac OS

Answer (score 4):

You can add files in three ways

- If you want to add single file use `git add filenamewithpath`
- If you want to add multiple files use `git add .`
- at a time you can add all files and you can write the commit message through this command

  `git commit -a -m 'your commit message'`

Comment: or just `git commit -am 'your commit message'` for short

Answer (score 3):

This similar thing happened to me. No matter what I did the file appeared modified. When looking at the diff it was changed as I had done in a previous commit. The file always appeared to be modified, even after committing the first time. Finally I removed the file. Committed the removal,which appeared like I had removed two files. Then added the file again. Quite odd thing that I have never seen before.

Comment: I had the same thing. In my case the file was renamed recently, idk what was happening but deleting and remaking (no commits in between) allowed it to be added

Comment: Exact same thing

Answer (score 3):

guys! maybe it will help someone, in my case, git didn't want to add and commit files, because I was trying to commit and add from the deeply nested folder, which doesn't contain git files. when I returned to the root folder, it added and committed easily.

Comment: This is an overlooked solution, especially in Windows. I just moved up one level from my deeply-nested current location and it did the trick. Wondering if this is somehow related to a long filename limit in Windows or Git? Meaning, the entire path to my current location combined with the entire path to the other deeply-nested files I want to stage exceeds a limit? (I've enabled long filename support in both Windows and Git, but... maybe?)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error:

```
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'develop' at the same time.
```

Then with `git status`:

```
$ git status
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitmodules.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   .gitmodules
        new file:   submodule_dir

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   submodule_dir (modified content)
```

and `git diff` showed:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/somedir b/somedir
--- a/somedir
+++ b/somedir
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit some-commit-hash
+Subproject commit some-commit-hash-dirty
```

The issue was that I was trying to add a branch that did not yet exist in the submodule repository.

Answer (score 1):

So basically if you encounter `(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)` it means you have (internal repos) ie `.git` file in your subfolders; and recent changes to the files have not been registered to these (internal repos).

1. One way is to update the (internal repos) i.e `git [add & commit]` all the changes in the internal repos.

or

2. Discard the internal repos.

Answer (score 0):

It had happened with me just yesterday dude, in my case, the reason was because I was trying to call git from a subdirectory of my project. Then I used the "*git add --all*" and it solved the problem, also I had gone to the right directory above it also would solved de problem.

But what I do not get was: why in the world the git status, and git --all command was working from a subdirectory anyway? .-.

Hope it help =)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that the same very file is in stash and is in conflict with the current copy.

If this is the case, `git stash drop` - will drop the stash (with the file in conflict) and allow you to add the modified file to the index.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset .
```

This did the work for me. unstaging all files that were ready for commit the (modified content) file included

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had two files with the same name in the same location, just different capitalization and git seemed to be unable to distinguish between them so it was showing a misspelled file as being modified (it showed a proper diff), but I was unable to stage/commit it. The solution for me was to remove the incorrectly spelled file from git:
`git rm <incorrectly spelled file>`
this removed both files and so I needed to recover the correctly spelled one: `git checkout <correctly spelled file>`

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to a conflict between more than one git repo reference in the same or sub-folders.

Could be solved by

1. deleting the `.git` subfolder from the **untracked or modified** folder and
2. adding it again by `git add untrackedfolder`.

Answer (score -1):

Take a back up of the problematic files. Remove those set of files, commit the deletion, push once to origin.

Add back the files from back up and issue a fresh add , commit and push. The problem will be resolved.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You shouldn't need to delete and re-add files to a Git repo. The correct answer is [the accepted one](//stackoverflow.com/a/26051233/2747593), which states that the "file" is actually a submodule. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For incorrect answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/2747593)